# How to change the status bar text color to a custom one

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have been searching the web to a answer to this but only found how to change from white -> black and the other way around.

But i need to change the color of the status bar's text to a custom one, is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to set other than `white & black`.

Comment: Why the down vote?! did you even read the Q?! maybe is in the same subject but it is a totally different Q.. @MidhunMP

Comment: I am not your down-voter.

Comment: yeah i know..forgot the @ sign..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. As you've noticed you can only change it between the two colours.